# how to define int number using comparison operators

Tags: c++, comparison, int, operators

I want to declare

```
int x = it must be more or equal to 1 but less or equal to 100;
```

How can I do it? I dont want to use if condition, Im looking for something short and clear, if possible.

The x number is input, so program should accept only numbers in this limit.

Comment: I imagine you could make a `RestrictedRange<T>` class template that enforces it if you *really* wanted to.

Comment: ...  Is it a random int, or is it predefined?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you want in `x`? A random number from that range, or a restriction to prevent numbers beyond the range from being assigned to `x`?

Comment: I updated. I want a number in that range, inputed by user...

Comment: Well, your question made no sense before your edit, so it was hard to see *what* you were really asking for.

Comment: @user3272640 Please don't be abusive to people offering *free help*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're looking to error check on initialization.
If I were you I'd do something along the lines of.

```
int x;
cout << "Enter a value: " << flush;
cin >> x;
while(!((x>=1)&&(x<=100))) {
   cout << "Try Again: " << flush;
   cin >> x;
}
```

Comment: Initialise your variables and check the result of stream extraction for errors.

Comment: thank you, and what does the flush mean?

Comment: It flushes the buffer. It's standard procedure to do so in order to clear out any values hanging out where they are prone to pop-up unexpectedly. Usually a new line (std::endl) is used to do it but since you're taking input, I like to just use flush so it's more intuitive to the user (IE entering the value next to the prompt as opposed to underneath it).